# List of iPhone/iPad applications using PayPal

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, paypal

Can someone provide me the list of applications currently on app store which uses PayPal(not PayPal app by PayPal itself)?
Not sure weather Apple allows to use PayPal in an iPhone app for purchasing goods or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong, but apps with paypal are being rejected and we have to use In App purchases.

Comment: You are right but I am not using it for purchase of digital goods but for purchase of physical goods.So it should not violet apple's policy

Comment: Well as far as I remember - selling of physical goods is forbidden at all... Or maybe that stands for only In App purchases content...

Comment: Oh...if this is true then its really a matter of concern for me.Can you point any reference where I can get explanation for this?

Comment: Take a look at paragraph 11 of Apple's guide https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html But I don't have personal experience with this kind of apps, maybe there are some apps selling physical content.

Comment: this is only for digital goods and content - for physical goods (ecommerce) and subscriptions (like magazine subscriptions for example) you can still use PayPal (or any Payment provider as a matter of fact) and Apple's policy doesn't restrict it.

Comment: Is it really true? I saw apps rejected because of selling phisical goods, no matter what paymeny processing system they used.